# Unknown values when iterating over dataframe

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

I am using gender guesser library to guess gender from first name.

```
import gender_guesser.detector as gender
 d = gender.Detector()

 print(d.get_gender(u"Bob"))
 male
gen = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Kattie', "Jean", "Gabriel"]
female
male
female
male
male
```

But when I try to iterate it over pandas dataframe I get output as unknown

```
for name in df1['first_name'].iteritems():
print(d.get_gender(name))
```

Comment: please tell us how df1 is created, probably df1['first_name'] doesn't have the object type that the get_gender() function is expecting

Comment: Actually I got it: for i, name in df1['first_name'].iteritems():
    df1['Gender'] = (d.get_gender(name))

Comment: But @kaihami answer is more efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to go is using map.

```
df1['gender'] = df1['first_name'].map(lambda x: d.get_gender(x))
```

It will create a new column named "gender". I think it should be faster than iteritems.